# How to get a list of Application files from a site with Python Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a site (https://solmfers-minting-site.netlify.app/ for example) and I need get a list of all files in a directory path in Application files [In here precisely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck8L5.png) with Python requests and later work with them. How would that be possible?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory/41447012#41447012

Comment: @aminrd that would work if it werent a HTTPS site file directory :( thanks for helping tho

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.